# Make buttons take the full width of that row and split it evenly

Tags: css, flexbox

[image]

I have a modal

```
<div class="modal fade editModal in" data-backdrop="static" style="display: block; padding-left: 15px;">
        <div class="model-content" style="margin-top: 200px;">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-2 col-md-offset-5 col-md-2 text-center">
        <img width="80" src="/assets/be/img/baby/solidfood.png"><br><br><br>
        <input type="time" value="14:25" name="updatedAt" width="100%" height="80">
        <br><br>


        <div style="display:flex; justify-content: space-between;">
        

            <button onclick="updateLog('7873', '' )" class="btn btn-option btn-solidfood"></button>
            <button onclick="updateLog('7873', ''  )" class="btn btn-option btn-solidfood"></button>

            <br><br>

            
        </div>

        <br>



        <button onclick="updateLog('7873')" class="btn btn-option btn-success btn-block">Done</button>
        <br>
        <button onclick="deleteLog('7873', 'solidfood')" class="btn btn-option btn-danger btn-block">Delete</button>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

---

CSS

```
.btn-option {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
}
```

---

I have no idea why the buttons is not extended to the end!

It stopped at 95%.

How do I debug this and make it take a full width ?

Comment: Rather than snippets of code, can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to skin this cat.

### The bootstrap way:

This solution uses the built-in [bootstrap grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid) to accomplish the result you're looking for.
Remove the inline styling from your container `div` and replace it with bootstrap's `row` class. Then wrap each contained `button` inside `div`s with the class `col-lg-6`.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <button onclick="updateLog('8014', '' )" class="btn btn-option btn-solidfood"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <button onclick="updateLog('8014', ''  )" class="btn btn-option btn-solidfood"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Result:

[image: Result of bootstrap approach]

It looks clean require no additional css or overrides. However you are stuck with the bootstrap default column gap between buttons which may not be desirable.

Incidentally, if at all possible, I highly recommend upgrading to bootstrap 4 instead of 3, as it's much more flexible to tweaking this kind of thing without having to resort to writing more css.

### Custom CSS way:

If you want more control over the gap between the buttons, bootstrap may not be your best bet.

This is similar to the solution above from Cervus Camelopardalis and uses the [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) and [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) pseudo-classes.

Remove the inline style from the container element and instead give it a descriptive class name. I chose "double-btn" but use whatever makes the most sense to you.

HTML:

```
<div class="double-btn">
  <button onclick="updateLog('7997', '' )" class="btn btn-option btn-solidfood"></button>
  <button onclick="updateLog('7997', ''  )" class="btn btn-option btn-solidfood"></button>
</div>
```

In your CSS, add a rule for this class to set `display: flex`.
Then add another rule targeting any `.btn`'s that are children of this class, removing the default bootstrap margin.
Then add one last set of rules targeting the `:first-child` and `:last-child` pseudo-classes of those `.btns`, setting the `margin-right` and `margin-left` to half of your desired gap, respectively. I chose a ten pixel gap here, but with this approach you can change it whatever looks best to you.

CSS:

```
.double-btn {
  display: flex;
}
.double-btn .btn {
  margin: 0;
}
.double-btn .btn:first-child {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.double-btn .btn:last-child {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Result:

[image: Result of css approach]

From here, you can adjust the above `margin-right` and `margin-left` values to change the size of the gap between buttons.

Answer (score 3):

## The cause

The problem was caused by the `margin-right: 10px;`.

```
.btn, .btn:hover {
    color: white;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

[image: Before]

## A solution

So, what should you do? Setting `margin-right: 0px;` would produce the result you can see below. This is not what you want because there's no space in-between these two elements.

[image: Don't want]

You need to set `margin-right: 0px;` only to the right (i.e., last) element. You can do this by adding this:

```
.btn:last-child, .btn:last-child:hover {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

This will produce the result you can see below.

[image: Solution]

Comment: https://mybabies.app/baby/540c7f5b-2653-4e5f-b7e0-89f48193ef9c?code=kunlun

Comment: I have created a tested user for you, please click on the solid food 2:26 PM, you will see that menu pop up, and buttons extended fully to the right.

Comment: Thanks for your details answer. I wish I can accept your answer also. Andrew just started and I decided to reward him. But thanks again for ur answer.

Comment: I was also thinking about Bootstrap, but didn't want to change much of your code because you might not be familiar with it. But yeah, he basically copied my CSS part using `:last-child` (or `:first-child`, whatever) and got an idea from my answer (he answered later than I did). I don't think it's fair because I put quite a lot of time into this and then someone copies your answer (spending less time because someone already found a solution) and get his/her answer accepted just because he/she is a beginner. It sucks.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing those two `<br>` tags inside the `<div>`

```html
    <div style="display:flex; justify-content: space-between;">
            
    
                <button onclick="updateLog('7873', '' )" class="btn btn-option btn-solidfood"></button>
                <button onclick="updateLog('7873', ''  )" class="btn btn-option btn-solidfood"></button>

                <!-- Try removing these -->
                <br><br> 
    
                
            </div>
```

I don't think you'll need them inside a flexbox anyways.

Or maybe it's the `padding-left:14px` on the parent `div` that's causing this.Try changing that too and this should fix it.

Comment: Let me try thanks 

Comment: Result seems to be the same, I updated the prod server base on your comment/answer. Any other hint ?

Comment: @code8888 I edited my answer. If the problem persists, please go through the bootstrap documentation on how to fix this issue. This is why i like to have custom styles over using a css Framework.

Answer (score 2):

I opened your code provided and unchecked "margin-right:10px;" and it removed the margin on the right side of the button so that the buttons take up the full width of the row (parent element) and both buttons are taking half of the row. See image: [CSS code highlighted in yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnUGX.png) and [Fixed App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVwLa.png)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have `margin-right` on those two buttons, because your buttons have width of 100% and there is space between them and at the end of that div.

Try adding `margin: 0;` on `.btn-option`.

If this doesn't do the trick try setting `white-space: normal;` on parent div.